# How to display image/screenshot in python window without saving it

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I want to display my screenshot in new tkinter window (TopLevel) but I don't want to save it on pc. When I save it it's working fine but when I try to load screenshot from memory I have error: image doesn't exist.

My main window is `root = Tk()`

I call this function from button:

```
def screenshot():
    x = 500
    y = 500
    im1 = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, 100, 100))
    im1.save('test.png')

    New = Toplevel(root)
    im1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("test.png"))
    image1 = Label(New, image = im1)
    image1.image = im1
    image1.place(x=0, y=0)
```

And this works good, but when I try this:

```
def screenshot():
    x = 500
    y = 500
    im1 = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, 100, 100))

    New = Toplevel(root)
    image1 = Label(New, image = im1)
    image1.image = im1
    image1.place(x=0, y=0)
```

I got error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=100x100 at 0xB4367F0>" doesn't exist
```

How can I display my screenshot without saving it?

EDIT:
I bypass my own problem using `os.remove` code looks like this:

```
def screenshot():
    x = 500
    y = 500
    im1 = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, 100, 100))
    im1.save('test.png')

    New = Toplevel(root)
    im1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open('test.png'))
    image1 = Label(New, image = im1)
    image1.image = im1
    image1.place(x=0, y=0)
    os.remove('test.png')
```

And this is working pretty well but I'm still interested if I can do it without `im1.save` somehow.
I'm pretty new into programming, so please give me hints if my solution is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to your problem is very simple. From the error message `"_tkinter.TclError: image "<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=100x100 at 0xB4367F0>" doesn't exist"` I see that the image is in `PIL` format. Basically you just need to import [`ImageTk`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm) from PIL library and do `im1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im1)` in your function after you capture the screen.

**Here is your function.**

```
def screenshot():
    x = 500
    y = 500
    # Can use ImageGrab to capture the screen as well
    im1 = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, 100, 100))

    New = Toplevel(root)
    im1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im1)      # converting PIL to support Tkinter format
    image1 = Label(New, image = im1)
    image1.image = im1
    image1.place(x=0, y=0)
```

---

If you are using *pyautogui* just to capture the screen then I would recommend [`from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageTk`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/reference/ImageGrab.html) with this way you don't even need *pyautogui* and replace it with `ImageGrab.grab(bbox))`.

**Sample:**

```
from tkinter import *
import pyautogui
from PIL import ImageTk, ImageGrab

root = Tk()

def screenshot():
    x = 500
    y = 500

    # ----They both show the same results-----

    # im1 = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(x, y, 100, 100))   
    im1 = ImageGrab.grab((x, y, x+100, y+100)) # bbox =  (x1, y1, x2, y2)  

    New = Toplevel(root)
    im1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im1)
    image1 = Label(New, image = im1)
    image1.image = im1
    image1.place(x=0, y=0)

Button(root, text='ScreenShot', padx=10, command=screenshot).pack(padx=10, pady=10)

mainloop()
```